# Laravel. Динамическое построение условий запроса в БД

Tags: php, laravel

Допустим, строим в БД запрос типа:

```
     $s = Objects::select('Objects.*', 'cities.name as city')
    ->join('cities', 'Objects.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
    ->get();
```

Но могут ещё понадобится дополнительные условия, типа:

```
->where('cities.id', '=', 1)
```

А могут и не понадобится. И таких уточнений может быть множество.
При работе со строкой запроса вопрос решался следующим образом:

```
 if($reques['city']){

    $query .= "AND city.id = ". $reques['city']; 
 }
```

Как реализовать подобное инструментами Фреймворка?

Comment: В Laravel используется Query Builder, его можно получить до вызова get/find, и добавлять к нему все что вам необходимо.

Comment: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v2/introduction

Answer (score 0):

ты можешь модифицировать запрос как угодно по ходу конда, держа его в переменной, например:

```php
// Получаем инстанс Builder
$query = City::query(); // Или City::where('city_id', 123); Он тоже вернет инстанс Builder

if (true) {
  $query->where('a', 1);
} else {
  $query->where('b', 2);
}

// Точно так же можно работать со связями:
$query->with('relation');

$query->get();
```